# Web View loading URL - text is not wrapping

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am using a Web View in iOS in order to load a URL. Load of the URL works fine. Here is the code snippet:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://yahoo.com") else {
    return
}

webviewTerms.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:url))
```

The issue I am having is that the text being loaded in the URL is not wrapping and I can't even scroll to the right to view it.

If I view the same site using browser on my phone the text is properly wrapped, so it is not an issue with the website.

How do I get the loaded URL text to wrap properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason, it was because the Web View had no constraints defined. As soon as I defined constraints, the text wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Try making

```
webview.scalesPageToFit = true 
webview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: Try setting the zoom level